# Add line from text file to new text file if line does not exist

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a file that is operating as a database of sorts. I am obtaining information from an HTTP JSON, and after some processing I am able to get a text file, "temp.txt",  with something along the following:

```
Class: 00000001
Title: AAAAAAAA
Class: 00000002
Title: BBBBBBBB
Class: 00000001
Title: AAAAAAAA
Class: 00000003
Title: CCCCCCCC
```

where `Class` is an eight-digit number and `Title` is a string which can include pretty much any character. Each class has a specific title keyed to it and no class shares a title with another class, and no title shares a class with another title. The class/title pairing may be repeated within "temp.txt".

What I want to do is take the lines from "temp.txt" line by line and add them to a new file, Class.txt, but I don't want to add duplicates to this new file. E.g., the output from the above sample would have the duplicate 00000001 class with title AAAAAAAA removed:

```
Class: 00000001
Title: AAAAAAAA
Class: 00000002
Title: BBBBBBBB
Class: 00000003
Title: CCCCCCCC
```

Again, I need something generic as there can be multiple duplicates for different classes and I won't know which ones are duplicated. I also need to do this either with a Windows batch file or PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a batch script that should do what you want:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%X in (temp.txt) do (
>nul find "%%X" new.txt && (
echo.
) || (
echo %%X >>new.txt
)
)
```

Comment: This does work, but I found a simpler method with powershell (see below).

Answer (score 0):

For the initial formatting in my OP, however, MrGoodbytes13's answer works (I just switched things around because getting the info to the format in this post cut out a lot of extraneous code and gives me the final output I need to pipe later on to another program).

I was able to reorganize the files so the "class.txt" file read

```
"Class","Title"
"00000001","AAAAAAAA"
"00000002","BBBBBBBB"
"00000001","AAAAAAAA"
"00000004","CCCCCCCC"
```

I also created a "header.txt" file containing

```
"Class","Title"
```

I then used powershell to do the following:

```
Get-Content class.txt | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content "class_temp.txt"
Move "class_temp.txt" class.txt -Force
gc class.txt | sort | get-unique >> class_temp.txt
Move "class_temp.txt" class.txt -Force
Get-Content header.txt | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -Append class_temp.txt
Get-Content class.txt | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -Append class_temp.txt
Move "class_temp.txt" class.txt -Force
```

The first two lines remove the header from the file with the data. The next two lines sort the data and remove the duplicate lines. The last three lines create a text file with the contents of the header and the new pruned data.

I have things set up so the powershell script also appends the new class values that I am grabbing from the http JSON to the class.txt file so that when the above lines are run it will prune any new material added to the "class.txt" file produced by the script.